# Running Akka.Net on different processes on same node

Tags: akka.net

I am currently evaluating using akka.net for a planned (complex) application, which is currently considered to be a desktop application but should be open later to offer services also and scale horizontally.

There is the challenge that the application communicates and integrates hardware devices, which drivers may crash and corrupt the whole process. Thus, it is a requirement that those drivers run in a different .NET process/VM so that there is no danger that the main application gets affected by such crashes.

I see currently the following solutions:

a) Span different akka.clusters on different .NET VMs on the same machine to have this isolation. That seems doable but I am unsure about the overhead. My understanding is that within an akka.net cluster there is no possibility to isolate actors (that is for instance an actor with its children) in an own process. Also would I benefit from any akka.net features concerning fault-tolerance (e.g. could I trigger the recreation of the cluster/VM when it is detected that hardware drivers created chaos? )

b)Do not implement the hardware integration module (which commmunicates with the unreliable drivers) with akka but provide a classic .NET service, which communicates with the akka cluster via WCF or other means. This would be feasible but would result in a complex and not holistic architecture, which I do not like.

I would appreciate much if I could get any guidance here.